# How can I set max word count?

Tags: count, set, cpu-word, limit, sphinx

how can I do sphinx search set limit for the word count.
For example I have faceted search for 2100 products with 190 filters (price, color etc.) and result time is 0.004 second. Very good for me.
But there's something I 've wondered.

Faceted search example

- Blue(1700)
- Yellow(676)
- Green(224)

I want to this

- Blue(999+) *<- Sphinx count max 1000, not much more. How can i this? Is this possible?*
- Yellow(676)
- Green(224)

improves performance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting for this.

And even is was doubt it wold inprove performance. When doing the counting loop, would have to add a conditional, to check if above a threshold and if so do nothing, otherwise increment the counter. its less work to just to increment anyway.

Max_matches affects the number of groups more, rather than the count within.

Can do it in application code for display purposes if like.

Comment: Thank you for answer Barryhunter.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a limit on the amount of results returned in Sphinx for sure. With PHP, I can refer you this: 
http://php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.setlimits.php

Otherwise, check out the setLimits() function in the Sphinx API here: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html